# d3 time scale - last bar on graph is appearing outside of the graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm building a bar graph in D3 version 4, using a time scale as my x axis.  The axis itself renders fine, but the bars are off; the last bar in the graph is appearing *outside* of the range of the axis. How do I specify the proper range and/or x values?

[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/9w8ogo8t/3/)

Code Snippet:

```
const xScale = (width, dates) =>
  scaleTime()
    .domain([new Date(dates[0]), new Date(last(dates))])
    .range([0, width])

svg.select('g')
  .selectAll(`.${styles['bar']}`)
  .data(series)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', styles['bar'])
  .attr('x', (d) => x(d.date))
  .attr('width', Math.floor(width / series.length))
  .attr('y', (d) => {
    const scaled = y(d.count)
      return height - scaled > 0 && height - scaled < 2
      ? height - 2
      : scaled
  })
  .attr('height', (d) => {
    const scaled = height - y(d.count)
    return scaled > 0 && scaled < 2
      ? 2
      : scaled
  })
```

[image: Misaligned Bar]

Comment: It looks like the left edge of the final bar is appearing inside the range. I guess you could fix this by making your range slightly wider than `width`. (Say width + expected width of one bar.)

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't align things properly either. I've added a JSFiddle to illustrate the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not the width of the bar, or the paddings, or the range... the problem is the very concept of `scaleTime`. For instance, your first value is (I'm referring to the working example):

```
Wed Sep 21 2016
```

Which starts *before* 2017 but, because of the width of the bars, goes after 2017. Your last value is (again, working example):

```
Sat Sep 21 2030
```

Which sits just before the end of the domain (2030) but, because the width of the bars, goes after the range for that scale.

You can easily see this is this fiddle, where I set the domain going up to 2032: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/dnxc9cd9/

A simple solution: if you want a bar chart showing years in the x scale, parse your dates getting the years and use a band scale instead.

Comment: One of the reasons I was using time scale was that it automatically determines when _not_ to render ticks. For example, if a graph has 50 entries, it may only render 10 ticks to keep things legible on the axis.

Comment: `scaleBand` actually did end up being what I needed. I combined it with https://github.com/d3/d3-axis/blob/master/README.md#axis_tickValues to get me exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the left edge of the final bar is appearing inside the range. I guess you could fix this by making your range slightly wider than width. (Say width + expected width of one bar.)

```
const barWidth = width / series.length;


const xScale = (width, dates) =>
  scaleTime()
    .domain([new Date(dates[0]), new Date(last(dates))])
    .range([0, width - barWidth])

svg.select('g')
  .selectAll(`.${styles['bar']}`)
  .data(series)
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
  .attr('class', styles['bar'])
  .attr('x', (d) => x(d.date))
  .attr('width', Math.floor(barWidth))
  .attr('y', (d) => {
    const scaled = y(d.count)
      return height - scaled > 0 && height - scaled < 2
      ? height - 2
      : scaled
  })
  .attr('height', (d) => {
    const scaled = height - y(d.count)
    return scaled > 0 && scaled < 2
      ? 2
      : scaled
  })
```

Comment: Your solution constricts the graph further (now the last 2 bars are out of bounds). If I do `range([0, width - barWidth])` everything fits, but the bars have no padding.

Comment: If you add a working example, I'll be happy to help further. Or take a look at Gerardo's comment on the question.

Comment: Sure thing. Added above.